# Wait till repaint Component is finished

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a ScrollPane with a JPanel in it and I add about 200 Components in the `JPanel`. Know I want that the Vertical-Slider move to a specific Component.
But the problem is that when I am Calling:

```
myButton.scrollRectToVisible(myButton.getBounds());
```

`getBounds()` gives me width and height back with 0.

Obviously the elements are still not painted. How can I wait till the `repaint()` method has finished all it's work, so that I can then do the `scrollRectToVisible()`?

EDIT:

Maybe it help if I gave a Short Example of my Code:

```
 addElementsToPanel(); //function where I add Elements to the Panel

 myJPanel.revalidate();
 myJPanel.repaint();

 myButton.scrollRectToVisible(myButton.getBounds());
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Have you tried waiting for a `ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_SHOWN` event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` ?

Comment: Great this works i have put the line where I move the Slider to the right position in an SwingUtilities.invokeLater() and this works. Thank you many timees I worked on this since Hours!

PS: a little bit more answer then the invokeLater method call would be nice; next time ;)